# If the input contains one of the listed items , then do a specific output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
delete=["del","delete","unistall","delall"]

action=(input("Please Select An Action To Do: "))

if action in delete:

    print("Ok,I will Delete whatever you wish")
```

Can I make it detect if one sentence contains any of the delete keywords,so make it do the action? e.x. :UserInput="delete menu",can it detect the delete keyword and do the right action?

Edit:Thanks for helping me out , the answer was to replace the if line with :

```
if any(word in action for word in delete):
```

Comment: The first word, or at any position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `any()` function instead. This way, you can test if ***any*** word in the `delete` list appears in the user-inputed sentence:

```
if any(word in action for word in delete):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the input string to compare with delete list.
so, the for example the code like blow
delete=["del","delete","unistall","delall"]

```
action=(input("Please Select An Action To Do: "))

act_list =action.split(' ')

for act in act_list:
   for del in delete:
      if(act==del):
        print("Ok,I will Delete whatever you wish")
```

This code is just example, you can write better than above code.